# Extract 1 Column of data from SQL in Python

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have connected to a SQL database through python and am trying to extract one column of data. However, when I go to print what I extracted, it displays the following:

```
('A', )
('B', )
('C', )
('D', )
```

When I extract two columns, it prints:

```
('A', 'a' )
('B', 'b')
('C', 'c')
('D', 'd')
```

Is there a way to simply take the data in the first column without the additional `, )` or even transform into a dataframe while preserving the column names from SQL? I have found a lot of guides how to extract data from SQL, but none showing ability to operate as a dataframe and preserve column names.

Code to generate:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}'
                      ,server = 'server'
                      ,database = 'db1'
                      ,trusted_connection=True
                      ,user='user')
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
        '''SELECT
                Column_One
                --,Column_Two
            FROM db1.table''')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}'
                      ,server = 'server'
                      ,database = 'db1'
                      ,trusted_connection=True
                      ,user='user')
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
        '''SELECT
                Column_One
                --,Column_Two
            FROM db1.table''')

final_result = [list(i) for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: This prints a list of lists such that each inner list is 1 element. It works for my simple tasks, but does not preserve the columns. Very simplistic for small stuff like I need now.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
def keyword_sql():
    try:
        db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://user:password@server/database'
        db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
        df = pd.read_sql('SELECT keyword, category FROM additional_data_dictionary', con=db_connection)
        return df
    except:
        print("mysql connection issue - ignoring the user input")
        sys.exit(1)
```

See if this helps, I am not using pyodbc, I am using "sqlalchemy"
- this code directly returns the pandas dataframe